# What does tANI_U32 data type mean?

Tags: c

I am reading a library and in that I came across this data type. What does this actually mean? Can any one explain to me? I have tried searching for it in Google and also asked my peers, but found no answers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be assign alternative names to existing any data type, structure or union using `typedef`.

In Qualcomm Atheros driver it is like `typedef tANI_U32 eQWPttStatus;`. and `eQWPttStatus` is probably structure.

Comment: hi sir thank u for the answer , but what does ANI in general represent in programming , as t here means type in DATA TYPE

Comment: @user3772235 I think this stand for some sort name of something related to for which type this application used OR say from which company this source belongs to. It's is very hard to say `ANI` stands for what. It may be for `Atheros Network Inc.` or `Atheros Netword Interface` or anything else.